# How to add custom automatic generated topics in Sandcastle

Tags: sandcastle

Does anyone know how to add custom reference topics to a Sandcastle help file?
I have a .net wcf rest service library and I want to produce reference documentation for the rest API as they are seen from an http client point of view.

For example:

1. Instead of methods within classes I would like to expose endpoint uris within a service.
2. Instead of request method parameters I would like them listed in a table indicating if they are query string parameters
3. For .net dto classes I want them listed in a JSON like fashion.

I know I had to customize some presentation xsl styles in Sandcastle, but first of all I do not know how to add those custom topics and inject the xsl transforms to generate content for those topics, within Sandcastle Help Builder build process?

I know there is support to add conceptual topics, but their content seems targeted to be manually generated and from which you can add references to automatic generated documentation with codeEntityRefferences or am I missing something here?